# Please help me: how to deserialize this xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, deserialization

I'm working since a week about this problem: i don't know how to deserialize the XML below.
I receive xml from a web service. The xml always contains one and only one row (result).

I've create the XSD then the .cs class with the xsd tool (in VisualStudio 2008), but when i do this:

```
// language: c#
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewDataSet));
NewDataSet crm;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(retXmlStream))
{
    crm = (NewDataSet)ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

I always receive "Error in XML document (2, 2)"

This is the XML returned from the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CRMMessage language="en_US" currency="USD" isTrustedSAT="false" hostversion="1.00">
  <RequestCode>GetCustomer</RequestCode>
  <ResponseCode>A</ResponseCode>
  <ResultSet>
    <ResultSetMetaData>
      <RSColumn name="PRIMARYPOSREF" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="ACTIVE" type="boolean" nullable="false"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="firstName" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="LastName" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="postalCode" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="city" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="county" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="addressline1" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="addressline2" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
      <RSColumn name="organizationname" type="string" nullable="true"></RSColumn>
    </ResultSetMetaData>
    <Rows>
      <Row id="168209">
        <Col>168209</Col>
        <Col>1</Col>
        <Col>John</Col>
        <Col>Doe</Col>
        <Col>12345</Col>
        <Col>ROME</Col>
        <Col>RM</Col>
        <Col>Via Verdi 1</Col>
        <Col>Secondo Piano</Col>
        <Col>ACME Ltd</Col>
      </Row>
    </Rows>
  </ResultSet>
</CRMMessage>
```

Thanks to all for your precious help.
Davide.

Comment: I guess you need to have root element in your result xml.

Comment: An edit was just made, correcting th emost obvious problem with the xml. Are we to assume that _this_ is the actual XML, or was that the earlier version? Because the earlier version _did_ indeed have an XML error at the given location, this one does _not_, making the error message all the stranger.

Comment: @oerkelens The edit fixed a formatting issue that prevented displaying the closing `</CRMMessage>` tag (which was there all along, jus not displayed). It changed nothing in line 2 column 2 of the XML.

Comment: You are trying to deserialize an XML document containing a `CRMMessage` using a class called `NewDataSet`. Are you sure you are using the correct class?

Comment: line2, column 2 is the tag that appeared not to be closed. So i am at a loss as to the provenanc of the error, i guess we need to see (some of) the generated xsd-based code to understand what is happening :)
@KrisVandermotten: NewDataSet is the default name, so it is not strnage that it pops up. It is worth checking though! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<CRMMessage tag is not closed.
```

Comment: It was, but that was not visible due to bad formatting of the question. I've edited the question. Note also that the error happens at line 2, column 2, not at the end of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Root element i.e CRMMessage node need to be closed at  the end of XML.
Just check whether you are getting proper formatted XML from web services.

Comment: It is, but that was not visible due to bad formatting of the question. I've edited the question. Note also that the error happens at line 2, column 2, not at the end of the document.

Comment: Can yor share class view of NewDataSet ?

Comment: Just rename NewDataSet class to CRMMessage and try.

Comment: For serialization/Deserialization We should have same node name in XML and XSD.